# Is it possible to create an Excel array formula where each element n is the sum of the first n elements of another array?

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula

Assuming there is an array in cells A1# (for instance a sequence or an array of random numbers), I would like to obtain an array in cells B1# where each row (n) of the array is the sum from 1 to n of the rows of the first array. Is it possible to do so with a formula?

Answer (score 6):

In **B1** enter:

```
=SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET(A1#,0,0,SEQUENCE(COUNT(A1#))))
```

A simple example.  If **A1** contained the dynamic:

```
=SEQUENCE(10,,1,1)
```

[image]

Comment: Nice trick, thanks. I did not know about the SUBTOTAL function.

Answer (score 3):

If volatility matters and you have Office 365, you can also do:

```
= MMULT(--( SEQUENCE( 1, ROWS( A1:A10 ) ) <= SEQUENCE( ROWS( A1:A10 ) ) ), A1:A10 )
```

[image]

This will compute faster.

Comment: Thanks. It does work too, but to use it with an array of arbitrary length it would need to be slightly modified to refer to the array instead of a fixed range:
= MMULT(--( SEQUENCE( 1, ROWS( A1# ) ) <= SEQUENCE( ROWS( A1# ) ) ), A1# )

Comment: Oops - wasn't paying attention to that detail, but yes it does arrays as well.

Answer (score 2):

One more version:

```
=SUMIF(OFFSET(A1,,,SEQUENCE(COUNT(A1#))),"<>")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are in the beta channel you can use the new SCAN function.

Cell A1

```
=SEQUENCE(10,,1,1)
```

Cell B1

```
=SCAN(0,A1#,LAMBDA(a,b,a+b))
```